# Prime dividing the divisors sum of a prime-power

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, divisor-sum

> Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct primes and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that:
>
> $q\vert \sigma(p^n)=\frac{p^{n+1}-1}{p-1}$ and $q \vert p-1$
>
> How would one go about proving the equivalence to $q \vert n+1$?

It would be pretty useful to have $\frac{p^{n+1}-1}{p-1}\equiv n+1\,(\text{mod }q)$ in the case of $q \vert p-1$, since the result would follow immediately. Unfortunately I do not know how to prove this (or even know if it holds true). Since $$\sigma(p^n)=\frac{p^{n+1}-p+p-1}{p-1}=\frac{p^{n+1}-p}{p-1}+1=p\,\sigma(p^{n-1})+1$$
This should be equivalent to $p\,\sigma(p^{n-1})\equiv n\,(\text{mod } q)$ but that doesn't seem helpful. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$q\mid p^n+...+p^2+p+1\implies p^n+...+p^2+p+1 \equiv 0 \pmod {q}$$

Since $$q\mid p-1\implies p \equiv 1 \pmod {q}$$

we have $$\underbrace{1+1+...+1+1+1}_{n+1} \equiv 0 \pmod {q}$$
so $q\mid n+1$.

Comment: Ah, now it makes sense! Thanks!